# Fast replace in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, replace

I have been trying to implement some modification to speed up this pseudo code:

```
>>> A=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
>>> B=np.array([np.power(A,n) for n in [3,4,5]])
>>> B
array([[  1,   1,   1,   8,   8,   8,  27,  27,  27],
       [  1,   1,   1,  16,  16,  16,  81,  81,  81],
       [  1,   1,   1,  32,  32,  32, 243, 243, 243]])
```

Where elements of A are often repeated 10-20 times and the shape of B needs to be retained because it is multiplied by another array of the same shape later.

My first idea was to use the following code:

```
uA=np.unique(A)
uB=np.array([np.power(uA,n) for n in [3,4,5]])
B=[]
for num in range(uB.shape[0]):
    Temp=np.copy(A)
    for k,v in zip(uA,uB[num]): Temp[A==k] = v
    B.append(Temp)
B=np.array(B)
### Also any better way to create the numpy array B?
```

This seems fairly terrible and there is likely a better way. Any idea on how to speed this up would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Here is an update. I realized that my function was poorly coded. A thank you to everyone for the suggestions. I will try to rephrase my questions better in the future so that they show everything required.

```
Normal='''
import numpy as np
import scipy
def func(value,n):
    if n==0: return 1
    else: return np.power(value,n)/scipy.factorial(n,exact=0)+func(value,n-1)
A=np.random.randint(10,size=250)
A=np.unique(A)
B=np.array([func(A,n) for n in [6,8,10]])
'''

Me='''
import numpy as np
import scipy
def func(value,n):
    if n==0: return 1
    else: return np.power(value,n)/scipy.factorial(n,exact=0)+func(value,n-1)
A=np.random.randint(10,size=250)
uA=np.unique(A)
uB=np.array([func(A,n) for n in [6,8,10]])
B=[]
for num in range(uB.shape[0]):
    Temp=np.copy(A)
    for k,v in zip(uA,uB[num]): Temp[A==k] = v
    B.append(Temp)
B=np.array(B)
'''


Alex='''
import numpy as np
import scipy
A=np.random.randint(10,size=250)
power=np.arange(11)
fact=scipy.factorial(np.arange(11),exact=0).reshape(-1,1)
power=np.power(A,np.arange(11).reshape(-1,1))
value=power/fact
six=np.sum(value[:6],axis=0)
eight=six+np.sum(value[6:8],axis=0)
ten=eight+np.sum(value[8:],axis=0)
B=np.vstack((six,eight,ten))
'''
Alex='''
import numpy as np
import scipy
A=np.random.randint(10,size=250)
power=np.arange(11)
fact=scipy.factorial(np.arange(11),exact=0).reshape(-1,1)
power=np.power(A,np.arange(11).reshape(-1,1))
value=power/fact
six=np.sum(value[:6],axis=0)
eight=six+np.sum(value[6:8],axis=0)
ten=eight+np.sum(value[8:],axis=0)
B=np.vstack((six,eight,ten))
'''

Alex2='''
import numpy as np
import scipy
def find_count(the_list):
    count = list(the_list).count
    result = [count(item) for item in set(the_list)]
    return result
A=np.random.randint(10,size=250)
A_unique=np.unique(A)
A_counts = np.array(find_count(A_unique))
fact=scipy.factorial(np.arange(11),exact=0).reshape(-1,1)
power=np.power(A_unique,np.arange(11).reshape(-1,1))
value=power/fact
six=np.sum(value[:6],axis=0)
eight=six+np.sum(value[6:8],axis=0)
ten=eight+np.sum(value[8:],axis=0)
B_nodup=np.vstack((six,eight,ten))
B_list = [ np.transpose( np.tile( B_nodup[:,i], (A_counts[i], 1) ) ) for i in range(A_unique.shape[0]) ]
B = np.hstack( B_list )
'''


print timeit.timeit(Normal, number=10000)
print timeit.timeit(Me, number=10000)
print timeit.timeit(Alex, number=10000)
print timeit.timeit(Alex2, number=10000)

Normal: 10.7544178963
Me:     23.2039361
Alex:    4.85648703575
Alex2:   4.18024992943
```

Comment: Append is slow, so is a python list compared to ndarray. Don't you already know the size of B? Declare it before the loop and just insert values.

Comment: Can you expand on this some. Do you mean np.empty(shape) then fill in the values?

Comment: Yes. If you are taking the power of each element to 3 different powers (3,4,5) in example then you know you get lengh of A * 3 elements.

Comment: Updated the pseudo code so that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of numpy.tile() and numpy.hstack(), as follows:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3])
A_counts = np.array([3,3,3])
A_powers = np.array([[3],[4],[5]])
B_nodup = np.power(A, A_powers)
B_list = [ np.transpose( np.tile( B_nodup[:,i], (A_counts[i], 1) ) ) for i in range(A.shape[0]) ]
B = np.hstack( B_list )
```

The transpose and stack may be reversed, this may be faster:

```
B_list = [ np.tile( B_nodup[:,i], (A_counts[i], 1) ) for i in range(A.shape[0]) ]
B = np.transpose( np.vstack( B_list ) )
```

This is likely only worth doing if the function you are calculating is quite expensive, or it is duplicated many, many times (more than 10); doing a tile and stack to prevent calculating the power function an extra 10 times is likely not worth it.  Please benchmark and let us know.

**EDIT:** Or, you could just use broadcasting to get rid of the list comprehension:

```
>>> A=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
>>> B = np.power(A,[[3],[4],[5]])
>>> B
array([[  1,   1,   1,   8,   8,   8,  27,  27,  27],
       [  1,   1,   1,  16,  16,  16,  81,  81,  81],
       [  1,   1,   1,  32,  32,  32, 243, 243, 243]])
```

This is probably pretty fast, but doesn't actually do what you asked.

Comment: Im not sure why people are so against list comprehension. In this scenario its about the same/slightly better then these other options.

Comment: @Ophion: are you sure?  Please compare with the broadcasting method above, not the one suggested by larsmans below (which requires an extra reshape and transpose).  I suspect broadcasting wins by a lot for large arrays (try 1k by 1k or so).

Comment: @AlexI: your version effectively reshapes `[3,4,5]`. When I run it on a larger example, it's a tad slower than my version, though probably not significantly so. `reshape` and transpose are very cheap.

Comment: @Alex: Ah yes, when there are many rows the broadcasting method above is much faster. This typically only has about three rows so the differences are fairly negligible. Its certainly interesting and I will use it in the future. For the np.tile I will give it a go; however, the order is important and not always sorted.

Comment: @Ophion: the np.tile is used to make the desired number of copies of each column in the result (given by A_counts); it doesn't require anything to be sorted.

Answer (score 4):

You can broadcast `np.power` across `A` if you change its shape to that of a column vector.

```
>>> np.power(A.reshape(-1,1), [3,4,5]).T
array([[  1,   1,   1,   8,   8,   8,  27,  27,  27],
       [  1,   1,   1,  16,  16,  16,  81,  81,  81],
       [  1,   1,   1,  32,  32,  32, 243, 243, 243]])
```

Comment: Any intuitive reason why (-1,1) is a coulm and (1,-1) is a row? Just trying to understand the logic. Or is it "just because"?

Comment: @user948652: try printing them. Or, if you're looking for a reason why the first index is the row index: that's just a convention.

Comment: Ah should have googled first, thanks anyway :)

newshape : int or tuple of ints
The new shape should be compatible with the original shape. If an integer, then the result will be a 1-D array of that length. One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.

Comment: This actually takes more time then list comprehension by about 5% according to timeit.

Comment: @Ophion: on my box, it's about 20% faster for your example data. When `A.size == 21` (7 distinct values), it's about twice as fast.

Answer (score 0):

My go at it with 200k iterations, the first method is mine.

```
import numpy as np
import time

N = 200000
start = time.time()
for j in range(N):

    x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
    powers = np.array([3,4,5])
    result = np.zeros((powers.size,x.size)).astype(np.int32)
    for i in range(powers.size):
        result[i,:] = x**powers[i]
print time.time()-start, "seconds"

start = time.time()
for j in range(N):
    A=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
    B = np.power(A,[[3],[4],[5]])
print time.time()-start, "seconds"

start = time.time()
for j in range(N):
    np.power(A.reshape(-1,1), [3,4,5]).T
print time.time()-start, "seconds"

start = time.time()
for j in range(N):
    A=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
    B=np.array([np.power(x,n) for n in [3,4,5]])
print time.time()-start, "seconds"
```

Produces

```
8.88000011444 seconds
9.25099992752 seconds
3.95399999619 seconds
7.43799996376 seconds
```

larsmans method is clearly fastest.

(ps how do you link to an answer or user  here without explicit url @larsman doesnt work)

Comment: You forgot to initialize A for every loop of larsmans answer. Updating for this, using timeit, and A=np.random.randint(20, size=500) initialize at the very start you will find they are very close together. Thanks for posting this.